# Does EMU8086 have a bug, or have I made a mistake writing this code?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I tried to do an exercise where I have to write in a 20 elements vector the first 20 numbers of fibonacci series, but i can't understand why the code is not working properly. It works for the first 10 elements of the series, but then there's some problem that i can't recognize. What do you think? This is the code I wrote:

```
DIM EQU 20
COUNT EQU 18
.model small
.stack
.data

 vect dw DIM dup ?

.code
.startup

mov ax,1
mov bx,1
mov cx,COUNT

lea si,vect

mov [si],1
add si,2

ciclo: mov [si],bx
       mov dx,bx
       add bx,ax
       mov ax,dx
       add si,2
       LOOP ciclo

 .exit
 end
```

---

**UPDATE**

I didn't paste the code exactly as it appears in my program. The program I am running starts with:

```
ORG 100h
```

I didn't think that was important so I left it out. Is it important?

Here is what I see when I debug my original code. I step to `ciclo: mov [si],bx` . *CX* has 8 in it.

[image]

When I single step the program then exits and it says `PROGRAM HAS RETURNED CONTROL TO THE OPERATING SYSTEM` as shown in this picture:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please provide a more detailed problem description than _"there's some problem that i can't recognize"_.

Comment: Your emulator is not at fault.

Comment: Yes, that was a copy/paste error. Regarding the line " mov [si],1", if I'm not wrong Intel uses little endian, and specifying the size of 1 is more correct, but is not that important. Anyway thank you for the help, now I'm going to post two screenshots because I found something strange during debug. If you still want to help me, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why your code is failing is because your original code has this at the top:

```
ORG 100h
```

In EMU8086 this has the side effect of creating your program as a DOS COM program (Not a DOS EXE program). With a COM program - if you place the data before the code it will literally start executing your DATA as code. In your case it started executing the garbage in your `vect` array, and then attempted (not successfully) to run your actual code. This is the cause of all the strange behaviour your program is exhibiting both when run and when it is debugged via EMU8086.

Since you clearly have a data area, and a stack just remove `org 100h` from the top which will allow EMU8086 to execute your code as an DOS EXE and not a DOS COM program.

---

If you want to create a DOS COM program then you'll need to remove the `.stack` directive. Move the `data` segment after the last executable piece of code, and in this case that is the code created by `.exit`. This ensures the DATA doesn't get executed as code when DOS starts your program at the top. This isn't an issue with DOS EXE programs in EMU8086.

```
DIM EQU 20
COUNT EQU 18 

org 100h             ; COM programs are placed 256 from beginning of
                     ; of segment so we need ORG 100h. This
                     ; also informs EMU8086 you want to make a COM program
                     ; and not an EXE program.

                     ; No Stack specified for a COM program as DOS
                     ; automatically places it at the top of the 64K segment
                     ; and grows downward toward the code and data.

.model tiny          ; Normally COM programs are TINY model (CS=DS=SS) 

.code
.startup             ; This isn't needed for COM programs but won't hurt.

mov ax,1
mov bx,1
mov cx,COUNT

lea si,vect

mov word ptr [si],1 ; To avoid a bug we want to update the WORD at [si]
                    ; not the BYTE.
add si,2


ciclo: mov [si],bx
       mov dx,bx
       add bx,ax
       mov ax,dx
       add si,2
       LOOP ciclo
       .exit        ; Program exits here

.data               ; Place the data after the code for a COM program

 vect dw DIM dup ?

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in EMU8086 and found two little mistakes : dot before `code` and intialize the data segment. Here is your code fixed :

```
DIM EQU 20
COUNT EQU 18
.model small
.stack
.data

 vect dw DIM dup ?

.code                          ;<=================================
.startup
mov ax, @data                  ;<=================================
mov ds, ax                     ;<=================================

mov ax,1
mov bx,1
mov cx,COUNT

lea si,vect

mov [si],1
add si,2

ciclo: mov [si],bx
       mov dx,bx
       add bx,ax
       mov ax,dx
       add si,2
       LOOP ciclo

 .exit
 end
```

Next screenshot proves that with the fixes the program works great (see the Fibonacci numbers on the bottom right?) :

[image]

Comment: I disagree that your fix does anything (besides the missing period). The `.startup` directive will emit the code to set _DS_ appropriately.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, in my EMU8086 it doesn't happen, I have to add those two lines to make it work.

Comment: What version are you using? On 4.08 `.startup` generates a `mov` to `ds` via the _DX_ register. Possible some older versions don't do this correctly.

Comment: Mine is 4.08, and the `.startup` directive emits 2 instructions to update _DS_ in my environment. And that is exactly what should be emitted for an **EXE** is MASM/TASM/EMU8086 .

Comment: I didn't run the EXE, but when the emulator generates an **_EXE_** with a PSP (Rather than a COM program internally) it emulates an EXE environment). When you open up EMU8086 it asks if you want to generate an EXE or COM, but that can be overridden with the appropriate `#` directive on the first line of the file or changed by using `.model tiny`

Comment: Your code works Josè, thank you. If you still want to help me, I found something strange during debug, I'm going to post 2 screenshots.

Comment: @Pecho, post the screenshots to take a look at them.